# media conversion library

Tags: java, .net, php, python, ruby

I am building a mobile website were users can upload/download videos, and I need a library that  can convert the media files from mpeg, 3gp, mov  depending on what the user wants to download.

Do you happen to know a a library that can do this?

Comment: -1. This is just a statement sentence. It is not a question.

Answer (score 2):

You should not **only** search for Library to do this, if you are using linux you can find an **application** that do this for you with **CLI** support,then using that application cli you can change your format;

```
$result=shell_exec('application_name [parameters] input-file output-file')
```

for example you can use **[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)**

```
$result=shell_exec('ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -target vcd /tmp/vcd.mpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

[ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/) is a great lib for that.

[libavcodec](http://www.afterdawn.com/glossary/terms/libavcodec.cfm) to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FFmpeg](http://github.com/polly/ffmpeg/) gem in Ruby, it's really cool and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want something to use directly from Java, try [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler), a Java-based interface to [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). You could use as a command line tool.

Answer (score -1):

In the past, I ran [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) from the command-line and used it to do my conversions (it's free, supports nearly all audio and video formats, and works on many different platforms).  If you have VLC installed on the server, you can access it this way using any language that has a `system()` command or equivalent.